# From SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019 - No backupset selected to be restored

Tags: backup, sql-server-2014, restore

From a Windows Server 2012 / SQL Server 2014, I backed up a database to a `NNNN.bak` file on a network drive. When I log in to my new Windows Server 2019 / SQL Server 2019 and try to restore that, I get the famous

> No backupset selected to be restored

error on the upper-left corner of the screen when I select a `NNNN.bak`.

1. I tried several things like checking/adding the file extension .BAK, restore from a local drive, different checkboxes in "General", "Files", "Options" menu.
2. Important: with the same exact conditions 5 other databases got restored and the other four are not cooperating within the same week.
3. I checked my user permissions inside databases and both SQL servers. I am an administrator with almost all privileges.
4. I tried `restore verifyonly...`  and `restore header...` etc

Comment: What exact message do you get when running `RESTORE DATABASE... FROM DISK....` Does SQL Server service account have read permissions on the file? Is the database user `sa` or other admin?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Using the network path provided by the company R:\erts..\nnn...  failed. restore succeeded using server on the same network with \\Qdata...\nnn.. path as shown in the screenshot.